# React Native change background color on container view doesn't work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am new to react native. I tried to change the background view on the container seems like it doesn't work. I attached the codes below.
Could anyone here tell me what is wrong with the code below?

```
const HomeScreen = () => {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#FF0000' }}>
        <Text style={{
          color: COLORS.Text,
          marginLeft: 14,
          marginTop: 16,
          width: 100,
          height: 20
        }}>Hello world</Text>
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the below code:

```
import React from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, Text, SafeAreaView } from 'react-native';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.text}>Page content</Text>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor:'green'
  },
  text: {
    fontSize: 25,
    fontWeight: '500',
  },
});

export default App;
```

For more information, you can explore [SafeArea Documentation.](https://reactnative.dev/docs/safeareaview)

Comment: sorry, I found a problem  I wrapped my HomeScreen inside NavigationContainer from 'react-navigation/native'
And it doesn't show any background color.